# AWS ECS tasks are being killed by OOM without leaving any trace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, datadog

I have an ECS cluster where I place a container that runs as a daemon to monitor all other processes. However, I'm seeing this containers being killed by OOM from time to time without leaving a trace. I just happened to spot one of them being killed. This is causing some log duplication but I wonder if there is a way to trace these restarts because when I look on the ECS Cluster events, there are no information about this tasks being restarted by any means.

I know more from kubernetes so I would say an analogy here. When this happens on kubernetes you would see a `RESTARTS` counter when you get information from all pods (`kubectl get pods`) is there any way to find this information on AWS ECS tasks? I'm struggling to find on documentation

I identified the tasks, and also I identified the status of each tasks to gain more information, but I'm unable to find any hint that the process was restarted or killed before.

this is a task detail example

```yaml
- attachments: []
  attributes:
  - name: ecs.cpu-architecture
    value: x86_64
  availabilityZone: us-east-2c
  clusterArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:99999999999:cluster/dev
  connectivity: CONNECTED
  connectivityAt: '2023-01-24T23:03:23.315000-05:00'
  containerInstanceArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:99999999999:container-instance/dev/eb8875fhfghghghfjyjk88c8f96433b8
  containers:
  - containerArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:99999999999:container/dev/05d4a402ee274a3ca90a86e46292a63a/e54af51f-2420-47ab-bff6-dcd4f976ad2e
    cpu: '500'
    healthStatus: HEALTHY
    image: public.ecr.aws/datadog/agent:7.36.1
    lastStatus: RUNNING
    memory: '750'
    name: datadog-agent
    networkBindings:
    - bindIP: 0.0.0.0
      containerPort: 8125
      hostPort: 8125
      protocol: udp
    - bindIP: 0.0.0.0
      containerPort: 8126
      hostPort: 8126
      protocol: tcp
    networkInterfaces: []
    runtimeId: 75559b7327258d69fe61cac2dfe58b12d292bdb7b3a720c457231ee9e3e4190a
    taskArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:99999999999:task/dev/05d4a402ee274a3ca90a86e46292a63a
  cpu: '500'
  createdAt: '2023-01-24T23:03:22.841000-05:00'
  desiredStatus: RUNNING
  enableExecuteCommand: false
  group: service:datadog-agent
  healthStatus: HEALTHY
  lastStatus: RUNNING
  launchType: EC2
  memory: '750'
  overrides:
    containerOverrides:
    - name: datadog-agent
    inferenceAcceleratorOverrides: []
  pullStartedAt: '2023-01-24T23:03:25.471000-05:00'
  pullStoppedAt: '2023-01-24T23:03:39.790000-05:00'
  startedAt: '2023-01-24T23:03:47.514000-05:00'
  startedBy: ecs-svc/1726924224402147943
  tags: []
  taskArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:99999999999:task/dev/05d4a402ee274a3ca90a86e46292a63a
  taskDefinitionArn: arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:99999999999:task-definition/datadog-agent-task:5
  version: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after debugging a lot within the little information AWS provides for this use case, I ended up doing a process to find the answer:

1. List all tasks ids of a given service with aws-cli with flag `--desired-status STOPPED` and dump all to a json file

> aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev --service-name datadog-agent
> --desired-status STOPPED --output json > ecs_tasks.json

2. using jq and aws-cli, describe all previously found tasks ids to get further information on each one of them

> aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster dev --tasks $(jq -j '.taskArns[] |
> (.|" ",.)' ./ecs_tasks.json) --output yaml > ecs_tasks_describe.log

3. I could came up with a script to group and summarize the information but, since I only had to watch over 20 stopped tasks I ended up dumping the information in yaml format for easiness. I found two key properties on the output:

   - For each task object, there is a reason for why it was stopped that told me nothing more than it was stopped because a container within the task exited (doesn't say the exit code to help though)

> stoppedReason: Essential container in task exited

```
* For each task object, there is an array of containers objects under **containers** property. There you'll sometimes find **reason** property which can explain a bit more of why the container stopped
```

> reason: 'OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage'

Note: This information would give you all events for a given service for at least the last hour. In my case it gave me 8 hours of events but AWS documentation only promises 1 hour https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/stopped-task-errors.html

> Stopped tasks only appear in the Amazon ECS console, AWS CLI, and AWS SDKs for at least 1 hour after the task stops. After that, the details of the stopped task expire and aren't available in Amazon ECS.

Comment: I also found that AWS Console used to show the `stoppedReason` for the tasks in an older UI, but the newest UI hides this information so is harder to track.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ECS tracks or exposes a restart counter for tasks. If you want to be notified of tasks restarting you can create an [Event Bridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html) subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ECS Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html) with `EventBridge` and add any action like logging when such event happen.